# DataAccessException doesn't work

Tags: hibernate, spring, exception, jsf

i have set in my applicationContext

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>
```

and I try to catch the DataAccessException in ManagedBean. 
I have BusinessDelegate where i set @Transactonal.

The problem is:

```
    try
    {
        operazioneOk = businessDelegate.insertAuto(newAuto);
    }
    catch (DataAccessException e)
    {
        System.out.println("autoBean");
    }
```

the catch, work even if i don't set
`<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>`

but the strange thing is that in the console i have this exception:

```
AVVERTENZA: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
GRAVE: L'operazione «batch» 0 insert into public.auto (marca, modello, anno, km, cilindrata, optional, prezzo, occasione, id) values (w, ww, w, w, w, w, w, 0, 12) è stata interrotta. Chiamare «getNextException» per scoprirne il motivo.
AVVERTENZA: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23505
GRAVE: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auto_marca_key"
  Dettaglio: Key (marca)=(w) already exists.
GRAVE: Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
```

In the both case.
I think that something doesn't working.
Help me!

Answer (score 2):

the error from the stack trace is

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auto_marca_key"
  Dettaglio: Key (marca)=(w) already exists.
```

you are inserting a row that contains a column value that violates a unique constraint.

Comment: I know that: duplicate key is my problem but if i catch exception i always see the stack trace and at least System.out.println("autoBean");

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i have solved the problem myself.

The solution is setting the @Transactional propagation.
This is the method in my BusinessDelegate(SessionFacade):

```
@Override
@Transactional
public boolean insertAuto(Auto auto)
{
    try
    {
        return (autoDao.create(auto) != null);
    }
    catch (DataAccessException e)
    {
        System.out.println("aa");
    }
    return false;
}
```

while in DAO i must set:

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public PK create(T istance) throws DataAccessException
{
    return (PK) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(istance);
}
```

now everything work fine.
If someone see any problem in this approach please advice me.